# how to get ids/names/guids of selected pictures in picture library

Tags: select, moss, image

I have created a picture library and selected some pictures (through a check box). 
I have also added a menu item 'Download to my App' in the 'Actions' menu item in the standard toolbar.
Now, on clicking the 'Download to my App' option, I want to download the selected pictures programatically to my application.
So how can I get the ids/names/guids of selected pictures so that I can get SPListItem or SPFile objects of pictures.

Is there any token that I can get like ListId/ItemId in url?

Comment: If you have access to the Server then try to track down the template for a picture library, that way you can try and find the code used in some of the other picture library actions.  This may help.

Comment: Yeah. Pull up Reflector on any of the other actions you can perform on selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a check box for each picture that you wanted to select?  If so, how do you know which picture is associated with each check box?  Because surely that's the key to understanding the identity you need to do the download, isn't it?